# Config file not found run.conf.bat in jboss eap 5.1

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

When I try to start **JBoss EAP 5.1** through the **Command Prompt(cmd) in Windows** I got the following error.

`Config file not found run.conf.bat
Please check that you are in the bin directory when running this script.`

How can I overcome from that error

Comment: are u running it from <JBOSS_HOME>/bin directory 
?

Comment: yes. Also add to the **path** variables

Comment: can you try to re-download jboss 5.1 and try ? or u can copy run.conf.bat from any jboss 5.1 server and proceed ???